# ECS: firelens container can not push logs to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ecs, fluent-bit

I'm currently using ECS tasks (EC2 hosted) for a web application which use firelens Fluent Bit as log router. I set the output destination to S3 using [this plug-in](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/outputs/s3), but it gets an access error like this: `[error] [output:s3:s3.3] PutObject API responded with error='AccessDenied', message='Access Denied`.

My configuration file of Fluent Bit is like this:

```
[OUTPUT]
    Name          s3
    Match         app
    region        ap-northeast-1
    bucket        BUCKET_NAME
    s3_key_format /logs/app/%Y/%m/%d/%H/logs_ecs_$uuid_flush.txt
    store_dir     /tmp/fluent-bit/s3
    upload_chunk_size 10m
    upload_timeout 10s
```

What I tried are :

- Attach AmazonS3FullAccess policy to the task role.
- Add bucket policy which allows access from the task role like this:

  ```json
  {
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Principal": {
         "AWS": "TASK_ROLE_ARN"
     },
     "Action": "s3:*",
     "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME",
        "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*"
    ]
  }
  ```

None of these solves the issue. Is there any configuration I'm missing?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you can answer your question rather than updating the question with solution

Comment: Thanks for comment! I'll move solution to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by myself. My Fluent Bit container is using its host instance's role, so just add permission to the role solved the issue.